# mean for replicate lists in R?

Tags: r, mean, replicate

I have simulation and data structures as follows (just a toy example):

```r
foo = function(mu=0,lambda=1){
  x1 = rnorm(1,mu) #X~N(μ,1)
  y1 = rexp(1,lambda) #Y~Exp(λ)
  list(x=x1,y=y1)
}
mu = 1; lambda = 2 #true values: E(X)=μ=1; E(Y)=1/λ=0.5
set.seed(0); out = replicate(1000, foo(mu,lambda), simplify=FALSE)
# str(out)
```

Then we get a list `out` of `length(out)=1000`, with each list having `out$x` and `out$y`.
I want to compute the means for 1000 `out$x`s and `out$y`s, respectively.

Of course, I can reach my goal through a `not-clever` way as

```r
m = c() #for storing simulated values
for(i in 1:2){
  s = sapply( 1:1000, function(j)out[[j]][i] )
  m[i] = mean( as.numeric(s) )
}
m
# [1] 0.9736922 0.4999028
```

Can we use a more simple and efficient way to compute the means? I also try `lapply(out, mean)`
and `Reduce("+",out)/1000`, but failed...

Comment: if you need `Reduce` then do `Reduce(\(...) do.call(Map, list("+", ...)), out)` but you cannot directly divide by 1000 since the output result is a list

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your `Reduce` solution way; tks anyway! @onyambu

Comment: The code is quite compact. This will work even when you have foo returning a list of different values eg `foo <- function()list(x = rnorm(10), y = rexp(7,2), z = rpois(4,5))`. Then after you replicate: `set.seed(0); out = replicate(1000, foo(), simplify=FALSE)` you can then call the `Reduce` code I gave above and it will work

Comment: Indeed, your `Reduce(\(...) do.call(Map, list("+", ...)), out)` gives `Error: unexpected input in "Reduce(\" ` @onyambu

Comment: That is because you have an older version of R. Instead of `\(...)` use `function(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another option if the sublists are always the same length:

```
> rowMeans(matrix(unlist(out),2))
[1] 0.9736922 0.4999028
```

Or:

```
> rowMeans(replicate(1000,unlist(foo(mu,lambda))))
        x         y 
0.9736922 0.4999028
```

Comment: Very clean; this is the way (+1)!

Comment: What a simple and efficient way! @nisetama

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use `purrr::transpose`

```r
library(purrr)
out %>% transpose() %>% map(~ mean(unlist(.x)[1:1000]))
# Or: out[1:1000] %>% transpose() %>% map(~ mean(unlist(.x)))
#$x
#[1] 0.9736922
#
#$y
#[1] 0.4999028
```

Or a base R solution using `lapply` (which is essentially the same as your explicit `for` loop):

```r
lapply(c("x", "y"), function(var) mean(sapply(out[1:1000], "[[", var)))
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.9736922
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0.4999028
```

Comment: A structural and customizable solution!  Very impressed with  `library(purrr)` and right-way-use of `lapply` @MauritsEvers